# Highlight cells if a particular date falls in range of dates in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to put conditional formatting for below:

In a particular cell if I enter a date value as 12-Feb-18, then it searches in another worksheet a date range containing all Mondays like 01-Jan-18, 08-Jan-18, 15-Jan-18 and so on. If the value entered is a correct value then No highlighting is required, if value is not a Monday then cell value should be highlighted.

Please help.

Comment: What formulas have you tried? Should be a more or less simple one, checking if the date is equal, then if that date is a Monday.

Comment: Tried this =IF(J3,VLOOKUP(J3,Parameters!A2:A54,1)) but it is taking numerical value instead of date where J3 is the particular date value cell and Parameter!A2:A54 is the date range having all mondays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to highlight the cell if it's a Monday, you don't need to lookup a range of dates. Add a new conditional formatting rule with this formula (assuming the cell you want to format is F3):

```
=WEEKDAY($F$3) = 2
```

On the other hand, if you really want to match to a list on Sheet 2, cells A1 - A3, use the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(F3,Sheet2!A1:A3,0)),1,0)
```

Comment: For the conditional formatting, if you want to highlight the same day of the week as the date you entered, you can use this formula: `=WEEKDAY($A2)=WEEKDAY($J$3)`